# When parent is clicked hide div but when the child, then not

Tags: css

I want to achieve something like this, a full w & h container with a mini modal inside for auth, so when I click outside the modal and at the parent container, the class is to be hidden or something, but when to click on modal that to not happen.

```
<main>
  <section>
    {content}
  </section>
</main>
```

So somehow it will look like this:

```
|------------------------------|
| container                    |
|                              |
|      modal                   |
|      |---------------|       |
|      |               |       |
|      |               |       |
|      |               |       |
|      |               |       |
|      |               |       |
|      |---------------|       |
|                              |
|                              |
|------------------------------|
```

Whenever I click on the container the modal with parent container should be hidden, but when I click the modal this shouldn't happen.

Comment: You cannot make this only by CSS. You need Javascript.

Comment: @Azu what is the solution to that

Comment: Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: @Azu Not true, using checkbox it's pretty easy to do only with CSS.

Comment: Could you confirm what you want to hide when the user clicks in the container - is it just the modal element?

Comment: The container but when i click the modal I don;t want to hide the container

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pure CSS solution using the **checkbox input trick**.

You simply need to play with the `label` and `input[type=checkbox]` elements and their `:checked` state.

You can see I placed another `label` element behind the modal, that will trigger closing the opened overlay upon click.

https://jsfiddle.net/9s2fwtze/2/

```html
<input id="toggleLogin" type="checkbox" />
<main>
  <section>
    Content
    <button>
      <label for="toggleLogin">
          Login
      </label>
    </button>
  </section>
</main>
<div id="login">
  <label for="toggleLogin"></label>
  <form>
    I'll be the login form.
  </form>
</div>
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

#login {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#login label {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#login form {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}

#toggleLogin:checked ~ #login {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cant be done with CSS only, you also need Javascript.

In this example I used Jquery to toggle the active class and check which element is being clicked. If we click outside the modal it will be toggled.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
});

$('body').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('.modal') && !$(e.target).is('.button')) {
    $('.modal').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="button">Toggle modal</button>
<div class="modal">
  Hello 
</div>
```

Comment: Not true, with checkbox it can be done easily using only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide div by setting the value for `element.style.display` using Javascript.

One way to achieve your scenario would be to check the value of `event.target` and compare it with `modal` and `main`,

- **show** the div if the click is
  happening inside the modal - by setting the value to `flex` or `block`, etc. based on your scenario.
- and **hide** it if it is happening outside the modal, but within the main block - by setting the value to `none`.

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'flex'; // Show
  } else if (event.target == main) {
    document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'none'; // Hide
  }
}
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main" >
  <div id="modal" class="modal" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I am not sure which block you wanted to hide. Here, I am just hiding the entire main div. If you want to hide some other div, then, in the javascript, in `getElementById` method, you can pass the appropriate `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert an input element of type clickbox, with opacity 0 so it can't be seen (but it is still there) then you can make the modal display: none when input:checked using just CSS.

Note both the modal and input are positioned absolute.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.input .modal {
  display: block;
}

.modal {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 10vmin;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
}

.input:checked+.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">container
  <input class="input" type="checkbox">
  <div class="modal">modal</div>
</div>
```

The click acts as a toggle - first click removes the modal, next click shows it again etc.